# How to create Entity record with the predefined Id?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

Is it possible to recreate the entity record with the predefined Id?
The purpose of this question is to figure out how to create the entity record with the id you have provided.

For example when I delete Account record with the id '00-00-02' it does not exist in MS Dynamics CRM anymore. So now I want to recreate this Account record using REST API with it`s old id ('00-00-02').
Can anyone suggest me how to do it (or it is not possible)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D365 allows you to set the primary key Guid of an entity. Often when doing data migrations from one D365 org to another we'll push the id's across.

Here's an example of setting the accountId on a new account via the Web API. (Created in [Jason Lattimer's CRMRESTBuilder](https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder/releases/tag/2.6.0.0)):

```
var entity = {};
entity.accountid = "008A5AD9-59B7-43BB-BA41-BA59CB5B4769";
entity.name = "Acme Inc.";

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/accounts", true);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 204) {
            var uri = this.getResponseHeader("OData-EntityId");
            var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
            var matches = regExp.exec(uri);
            var newEntityId = matches[1];
        } else {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send(JSON.stringify(entity));
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an OrganizationService version of the same code:

```
Entity account = new Entity("account");
account.Id = new Guid("008A5AD9-59B7-43BB-BA41-BA59CB5B4769");
account["name"] = "Acme Inc.";
service.Create(account);
```

Answer (score 1):

Dynamics 365 (CRM) / Power Platform's Dataverse uses **sequential guids** to store massive amounts of data in a MS SQL database since the dawn of time. This allows lookup and searches to be quick when it comes to providing guids that are known as well as for indexing, storage, speed, etc.

The danger for using your own implementation of guids, i.e. *Guid.NewGuid()* creates a random guid which then needs to be indexed in the table.

To keep data consistent between environments, you should be exporting the Id's of entity data as part of your integration / configuration migration tools. But, only ones that have been generated by D365.

Both posts above failed to mention this crucial bit of information.

Examples of sequential guids << the way to go.

```
{218820BC-B557-DF11-A5C1-0050569B68DD}
{228820BC-B557-DF11-A5C1-0050569B68DD}
{238820BC-B557-DF11-A5C1-0050569B68DD}
{248820BC-B557-DF11-A5C1-0050569B68DD}
{268820BC-B557-DF11-A5C1-0050569B68DD}
```

Examples of randomly generated guids

```
{60450026-212D-488F-8CCC-B806BE3B2F2A}
{6A32A7CE-5857-4D95-8710-6E4663BC368A}
{6B6D8266-994F-407D-BA08-7F8376EC39A5}
{B0EB3EBC-4992-4563-85CB-1598780BDEC6}
{8F88A7D7-D399-4256-9925-310D11AF8120}
```

Rather create an additional field on the Entity table which is tied to a Unique Key Constraint (Keys under Table in Maker Portal) to store your "unique value" in. This can then be used in Upsert, Retrieve, Create and help with avoiding duplicate creates, leaving the D365 functionality as it was intended to be used.

Creating records with random guids is a very bad habit, which should be avoided at all costs.